# Fetching and updating long relational tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a task where I have db tables which have relations like this:

tbl_a - ida
tbl_b - idb | ida
tbl_c - idc | idb
 and goes on for another 12 tables…

I need to do some thing like this:

ida - make a new copy of ida row (ida_1). set old one non-effective,

idb - make a new copy of idb row, use ida_1 as the fk in this new row (idb_1); set idb row non-effective.

and goes on for few more tables.

Now I was wondering if there could be any easier/less time and memory consuming way to do this other than:

```
ida_1 = ida -> copy();
ida_1->setNewProperties();
ida_1-> save();

idbs = ida->getIdbs();

foreach( idbs as idb) {
    idb_1= idb -> copy();
    idb_1->setIdA(ida_1)
    idb_1->setSomeNewProperties();
    idb_1->save();

    idcs = idb->getIdcs();
    foreach (idcs as idc) {
        …same process...
    }
    idb->setANE();
    idb->save();
}
ida -> setAsNonEffective();
ida -> save();
```

Comment: strange variables without $ in your code. are you using constants?

Comment: You may build the mysql queries by yourself and send them to your db directly. It should be more efficient with less overhead.

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to show an algorithm/it's not a working code ofcourse.